# Use interface in ViewModel c# ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have some problem.

I have next model:

```
 public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public string Nazvanie { get; set; }

    public Author DocumentAutors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public List<IPerson> Authors { get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public class PersonUL : IPerson
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonIP : IPerson
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SecondNAme { get; set; }

    public string PostAddress { get; set; }
}
```

In .cshtml

```
@model DocumentViewModel
 @if (Model.DocumentAutors.Authors  != null && Model.DocumentAutors.Authors.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.DocumentAutors.Authors.Count; i++)
    {
      if (Model.DocumentAutors.Authors is PersonUL )
      {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DocumentAutors.Authors[i].Name" class="col-md-10 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.DocumentAutors.Authors[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DocumentAutors.Authors[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        }

    }

}
```

Model.DocumentAutors.Authors[i] don't contain "Name" field, because it's interface. I need cast it, but if i write

```
 if (Model.DocumentAutors.Authors is PersonUL )
      {
          PersonUL ul = (PersonUL)Model.DocumentAutors.Authors[i];
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@ul.Name" class="col-md-10 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="@ul.Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@ul.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

i will get html with wrong name like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  id="Name" name="Name" value="566">
```

instead

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  id="DocumentAutors.Authors[0].Name" name="DocumentAutors.Authors[0].Name" value="566">
```

and ModelBinder will not bint this field into Authors List.

Is there a solution for this problem or should I make one generic model for PersonUL and PersonIP with all fields, which I don't really like it?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but IMHO I don't see any advantages in the interface. It only makes the code more confused.

Why you don't try

```
public class Author
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public List<PersonIP> IpAuthors { get; set; }
    public List<PersonUL> UlAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

or even better

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public string Nazvanie { get; set; }

     public long AuthorId { get; set; }

    public List<PersonIP> IpAuthors { get; set; }
    public List<PersonUL> UlAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was done by analogy with the XSD schema for which the data is intended. The <choice> element.

Comment: You can  alway convert data from viewmodel to any schema or on the contrary convert from the schema to the viewmodel

Comment: It's not even about the schema, I have no idea how I can implement dynamic markup. The user should be able to select the type of Person object and their count. It should logically be one list. The presence of two lists imposes restrictions for me on the markup that I planned to do. Combobox with person type and corresponding fields for type and a button to add a new person.

Comment: It's up to you, but IMHO it is better to have two markups. Easier to read and  mantain